# EJB TransactionAttributeType - should I use MANDATORY or REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I need to update a table every minute by two different actions  (2 independent beans) at the same time

Bean A

```
 @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void stop()
    {
    stopMachin()
    } 

    @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
    public void stopMachin(){ updateTable ..}
```

Bean B

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void scan() 
{
stopscan();
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void stopscan() {updateTable..}
```

It failed with the error

```
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
Call: UPDATE ACTION SET DATE = ? WHERE (ID_AT = ?)
```

Why don't the `REQUIRES_NEW` and `MANDATORY` flags work?
New require means take the transaction of the client.

Do I have to put MANDATORY in the Bean B instead of REQUIRED?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the operation during your action (the SQLs) and the order of operation. Please give more details, what kind of operation are you performing and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

One methode every les minutes @Schedule(minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
Another every 2 minutes @Schedule(minute = "*/2", hour = "*", persistent = false)

And when at the same second, timers execute, it occurs often ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource